# Reg Exp replace to match hh:mm format in oracle

Tags: regex, oracle, time, replace, format

Write an oracle query using regexp replace to fix space and return hh:mm format.

```sql
with
  test_data (srt_tm) as (
    select '1:00'  from dual union all
    select '01:00' from dual union all
    select ' 01:00' from dual union all
    select '4:00'  from dual union all
    select '04:00' from dual union all
    select ' 04:00' from dual
  )
```

Expected output:

[image]

Query tried:

```
select (strt_tm,regexp_replace(strt_tm,'^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$','hh:mm') as "REPLACE" 
from test_data
```

Comment: Get rid of the extra set of parentheses.

Comment: You haven't said what is wrong with your query. But to start with you have an extra `(` at the start which will throw ORA-00907; and your column name `strt_tm` doesn't match the CTE definition. That's before you get to what your regex is actually doing...

Comment: Surely you don't mean `mm` (which is for month), but `mi` (for minutes)? In any case, that has nothing to do with the question; surely in **replace** you don't want to replace whatever from the input with the string `'hh:mi'` or `'hh:mm'` in the output. Also, two higher-level questions: (1) Why is "using regular expressions" part of the problem (that, if anything, should be part of the solution, not the problem itself), and (2) why did you need to change your user name to post the question again? What happened to your previous user name?

Comment: Why regex? `lpad(trim(srt_tm), 5, '0')` If you have to validate the time, then use built-in functions like [`validate_conversion`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD) instead of self-developed solutions which someone will need to support

Comment: @mathguy - second column returning hh:mi instead of values with corrected format (eg:instead 01:00 returning hh:mi).Ask is to use only regular expression and I posted same question in our earlier thread too.Could not post the same question so change the user name

Comment: yes.lpad working fine but need to use regexp as per instruction

Comment: Whose "instruction"? Why is "which tool to use" part of the business problem formulation? What else is there, which you have not shared with us, that makes regexp part of the ask, and not part of the answer?

Comment: If you *have to* use regex for some reason (because it is an assignment, a wish of some authority or any other external circumstances), then this question is not about Oracle (or any other *tool*) at all, but need to be decomposed: 1) What are possible patterns of the replacement part? 2) What regex you have so far and what do you feel is wrong with it? 3) Why the result is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just add extra 0 to hours and remove all except last 2 digits:

```sql
select 
  strt_tm,
  regexp_replace(
     regexp_replace(
        strt_tm
       ,'(\d+):'
       ,'0\1:'
     )
   ,'.*(\d{2}:)'
   ,'\1'
  ) as "REPLACE" 
from test_data;
```

Full example with test_data:

```sql
with
  test_data (strt_tm) as (
    select '1:00'  from dual union all
    select '01:00' from dual union all
    select ' 01:00' from dual union all
    select '4:00'  from dual union all
    select '04:00' from dual union all
    select ' 04:00' from dual
  )
select 
  strt_tm,
  regexp_replace(
     regexp_replace(
        strt_tm
       ,'(\d+):'
       ,'0\1:'
     )
   ,'.*(\d{2}:)'
   ,'\1'
  ) as "REPLACE" 
from test_data
```

Comment: select 
  strt_tm,
  regexp_replace(
     regexp_replace(
        strt_tm
       ,'(\d+):'
       ,'0\1:'
     )
   ,'.*(\d{2}:)'
   ,'\1'
  ) as "REPLACE" 
from test_data  where strt_tm='1:00'       -This returns 1:00 only instead of 01:00 in replace column

Comment: @Sona something nope: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=43e8a8b03c5792ca8df7e8d021a447c2

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any regular expressions for your test data; just trim the leading whitespace, prepend a zero and then take the last 5 characters:

```sql
with test_data (srt_tm) as (
  select '1:00'  from dual union all
  select '01:00' from dual union all
  select ' 01:00' from dual union all
  select '4:00'  from dual union all
  select '04:00' from dual union all
  select ' 04:00' from dual
)
SELECT SUBSTR('0' || LTRIM(srt_tm), -5)
FROM   test_data;
```

Which outputs:

> | SRT_TM |
> | --- |
> | 01:00 |
> | 01:00 |
> | 01:00 |
> | 04:00 |
> | 04:00 |
> | 04:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7c1db3605dae8fe9954f610a098efd25)*